# Objective-C timespan

Tags: objective-c, datetime, nsdate, timespan

In C#, if I wanted to parse out a string into a date and timespan, I'd do something similar to the following:

```
String input = "08:00";
DateTime time;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(input, out time))
{
    // invalid input
    return;
}

TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(time.Hour, time.Minute, time.Second);
```

My Google-Fu has been less than desirable in finding a way to convert this to Objective-C.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Date and Time Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/) will likely be helpful for finding an approach that best fits your needs. I'd bet that [NSDateComponents](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001502-DontLinkElementID_5) will be of particular interest — you can obtain an instance of this class from the [`-[NSCalendar components:fromDate:]`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/components:fromDate:) method.

As far as getting the date from a string, one approach you could try is using [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/), which has methods like `-dateFromString:` and `-stringFromDate:` to convert between NSString and NSDate representations. You can use `-setDateFormat:` to specify the format string to use for parsing. Once you have an [NSDate](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/) object, you can also use one of its `-timeIntervalSince...` methods to get an [NSTimeInterval](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-DontLinkElementID_26) which is a double value, measured in seconds.